# ライブラリからGooglePlayStoreのアプリを逆引きしたい

Tags: android

いつもお世話になっております。

商用アプリでHttpクライアントであるOkhttpの使用を
検討しております。

ライセンスの表記について、他社のアプリを参考にこれから画面表示する内容を決めようと思ったのですが、
ライブラリからGooglePlayStoreで公開されているアプリを逆引きできるようなデータベースサイトはご存知ありませんか。

Okhttpを使用するアプリ名をピンポイントで知りたいのではなく、汎用的に使用できるウェブサイトをご教授下さい。
例えば、このライブラリを使用してこのアプリはこんなことを実現してます、みたいなことがぱっとわかるようなウェブサイトがあれば素人目に面白いなと思い質問させていただきました。

以上、宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

個別のAndroidアプリで使われているライブラリを調べるには、各アプリの.apkファイルをPCへダウンロード、解凍（もしかしたら逆コンパイルも）という作業をひとつずつしていくしかおそらく方法がありません。

調べたところ、統計として利用され具合を出しているサイトはあるようなのですが、個別のアプリの使用状況を、さらには逆引きとなると見つけるのはかなり難しいのではないでしょうか。

http://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries/dev

Okhttp自体はメジャーなライブラリですので、導入事例等の記事や情報から使われているアプリを特定し、調査する方が効率的かと思われます。